# How do I extract lines from a file using their line number on unix?

Tags: unix, sed, awk, line-numbers, text-extraction

Using sed or similar how would you extract lines from a file? If I wanted lines 1, 5, 1010, 20503 from a file, how would I get these 4 lines?

What if I have a fairly large number of lines I need to extract?
If I had a file with 100 lines, each representing a line number that I wanted to extract from another file, how would I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like "sed -n '1p;5p;1010p;20503p'.  Execute the command "man sed" for details.

For your second question, I'd transform the input file into a bunch of sed(1) commands to print the lines I wanted.

Comment: +1, the thing to look up for the second part of the answer is `sed -f`

Comment: `sed -n '1p;5p;1010p;20503p inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt`

Answer (score 6):

with awk it's as simple as:

```
awk 'NR==1 || NR==5 || NR==1010' "file"
```

Comment: @michael, nonsense, awk can do that too.

Comment: ennuikiller, yes, I was mostly commenting on +1 for using awk in this context, ghostdog74, so can perl, python, pure bash, etc. It's a matter of opinion on the *right* tool for the job.

Answer (score 3):

@OP, you can do this easier and more efficiently with awk. so for your first question

```
awk 'NR~/^(1|2|5|1010)$/{print}' file
```

for 2nd question

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}(FNR in a){print}' file_with_linenr file
```

Comment: The second response is a bit obfuscated. To explain: `FNR==NR` will occur only when reading `file_with_linenr`, not `file`. In this case, the text of the line is added to a set `a`, and execution skips to the next line of input. Thus when reading from `file`, only the `(FNR in a)` case applies, and prints the text of the relevant line if its number was put in `a` in parsing `file_with_linenr`.

Answer (score 1):

This ain't pretty and it could exceed command length limits under some circumstances<sup>*</sup>:

```
sed -n "$(while read a; do echo "${a}p;"; done < line_num_file)" data_file
```

Or its much slower but more attractive, and possibly more well-behaved, sibling:

```
while read a; do echo "${a}p;"; done < line_num_file | xargs -I{} sed -n \{\} data_file
```

A variation:

```
xargs -a line_num_file -I{} sed -n \{\}p\; data_file
```

You can speed up the `xarg` versions a little bit by adding the `-P` option with some large argument like, say, 83 or maybe 419 or even 1177, but 10 seems as good as any.

<sub>*`xargs --show-limits </dev/null` can be instructive</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I'd investigate Perl, since it has the regexp facilities of `sed` plus the programming model surrounding it to allow you to read a file line by line, count the lines and extract according to what you want (including from a file of line numbers).

```
my $row = 1
while (<STDIN>) {
   # capture the line in $_ and check $row against a suitable list.
   $row++;
}
```

Comment: and you can use perl -e 'perlcode here' from the command prompt. Perl also has a range operator .. as in 3..12 which will allow you to create a  list of numbers where needed.

Comment: You should be using `$.`, which automagically contains the current line number

Comment: Anybody interested in Perl command line techniques might want to look at Minimal Perl, from Manning... http://manning.com/maher/

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if $. =~ m/^(1|5|1010|20503)$/' file
```